# can i add utm parameter to the Desktop SMS button from branch

Tags: branch.io

I need to add dynamic and page-specific utm paramenters to the Send me link button from Desktop SMS functionality on branch. Anyone know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Amruta from [branch.io](http://branch.io) here:

If you need to create a new link when using the SMS functionality you can set `make_new_link: true` in the options object argument of `sendSMS()` method, and `sendSMS` will always make a new link. You can then add the page-specific utm and dynamic parameters to the link data. You can check out an example mentioned on the Branch Github repo [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/web-branch-deep-linking#example-1).